# How to delete all files of a FTP folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp, ftp-client

I searched from several posts to find the solution for this problem but couldn't find it. I want to build a Batch file that goes to a folder on a FTP and Download all the records then Delete all of them.

So far I tried to Use the command "mdel *.*", please see the code below:

```
@echo off
echo user ftpUser> ftpcmd.dat
echo Password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /tst/>>ftpcmd.dat
echo binary>> ftpcmd.dat
echo prompt n>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mget *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mdel *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 77.99.999.999
del ftpcmd.dat
```

For this solution I noticed that if i use the command "delete" and specify the file it works. Like this:
    echo delete 312312312.csv >> ftpcmd.dat

But for some reason using mdel(like the example) it doesn't.

Do you know a better way to make it works?

Thanks

Comment: can you try it interactively and check the message if there's one ?

Comment: Hello Jean thanks for you reply, when i do any command like ls the prompt  seems to waiting something, please see the image: http://prntscr.com/cvk2ga

Comment: If the `ls` does not work, the `mget` (nor `mdel`) cannot work either as they use the `ls` to find list of files to download and delete. Post a complete output of the `ftp` showing that `mget` works, but `mdel` and `ls` does not.

Comment: Please do not post a solution in your question, put it into an answer instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdel` command needs to list files in the remote directory. The problem is that the Windows built-in `ftp.exe` supports an FTP active mode only. In this mode the server needs to open an incoming connection to your machine, to transfer the listing, what gets by default blocked by Windows firewall or any other firewall/proxy/NAT on the way between you and the server. That makes the `ftp.exe` most useless nowadays.

See my article about [network configuration for FTP active mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.

---

Use any other 3rd party FTP client. Most support the passive mode that does not have these kinds of problems.

As you have found out yourself, one such client is [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/).

Using [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), your batch file would be like:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://ftpUser:Password@77.99.999.999/" ^
    "cd /tst" ^
    "get *" ^
    "rm *" ^
    "exit"
```

Though, if supported by the server, consider using a [secure FTP over TLS/SSL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps), by replacing the `ftp://` with the [`ftpes://`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url).

See also a guide for [converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem: 
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm#examples

Using this software I was able to get and delete several files at the same time, and the code now is like this: 
option batch abort
option confirm off

```
open ftp://user:Password@77.XX.XXX.XXX
cd /tst/
get *.* d:\www\*.bak
rm *.*
EXIT
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

@Martin Prikryl Thanks for the software and the explanation.

Regards!